# Jquery Dialog - Object doesn't support this property or Method

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

My this code was working fine until I upgraded to Jquery newer version. Now I get above error.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css" />
    <link type="text/css" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ddsmoothmenu.css" />   
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ddsmoothmenu.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">    
         $(document).ready(function(){     
                $('#dialog').dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    autoOpen: false,
                    width: 760,
                    height: 'auto',             
                    close: function(event, data) {
                        $('#mainFrame')[0].src = "LoadingPage.aspx";
                    }
                });
                $('a[name="dia"]').click(function(){
                    $('#mainFrame')[0].src = this.file;
                    $('#dialog').data('title.dialog', this.innerText); 
//                    $('#dialog').data('width.dialog', this.diaWidth); 
//                    $('#dialog').data('height.dialog', this.diaHeight); 
                    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                    return false;
                });             

                if (document.getElementById('hidIsAdmin').value == "1"){
                    document.getElementById('liAdmin').style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('liReports').style.display = 'block';
                }else {
                    $('#liAdmin').remove();
                    $('#liReports').remove();

                }
                if (document.getElementById('hidCreate').value == "1"){
                    document.getElementById('liCreate').style.display = 'block';
                }else {
                    $('#liCreate').remove();
                    $('.edit_icon_link').hide(0);                   
                }
            });
            function hideEditIcon(){
                $('.edit_icon_link').hide(0);                   
            }            
    </script>
```

Comment: Is the jQuery UI version you're using compatible with the jQuery version? You might need to download a newer version.

Comment: What exactly did you upgrade? What file?

Comment: I changed jquery-1.3.2.min.js to jquery-1.4.4.min.js And jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js to jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js and Css jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.css to jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css. That's all. It worked fine with previous version.

Comment: Make sure the files are really loaded using HttpWatch for example.

Comment: This is how it was before  with old file names and now with new file names.   <link type="text/css" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ddsmoothmenu.css" /> 
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js"></script>    
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ddsmoothmenu.js"></script>

Comment: The error hints that `jquery-ui` is not loaded - when you browse directly to `js/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js` can you see it? Maybe you have typo in the file name.

Answer (score 3):

I had something similar happen (converting MVC3 ASP to Razor), and in my case, moving my `jquery-1.4.4.min.js` reference to my master page helped.

I say **"helped"** because now the open works, but the   `$(this).dialog("close");`   doesn't.

```
function ShowPopUp(strDivName)
{
    $("div[id$='" + strDivName + "']").dialog(
        {
            title: "blah blah blah",
            width: 600,
            modal: true,
            resizable: true,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            buttons:
            {
                "Save": function () { SaveThis(); $(this).dialog("close"); },
                "Cancel": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
            }
        }
    );
    $("div[id$='" + strDivName + "']").dialog("open");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the options available for dialog, I think autoResize has been renamed to resizable.

Comment: But it won't generate "object doesn't support.." error.. or can it? :/

Comment: { resizable : true } allows users to drag the edges of the dialog to resize it. AutoResize appears to be something else, although I don't see it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are not closing your `$(document).ready(function(){` ?

The `});` you are showing above closes the `$('#dialog').dialog({` but I don't see a close of the `$(document).ready(function(){` .

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){     
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        modal: true,
     autoOpen: false,
     width: 760,
     height: 'auto',    
        close: function(event, data) {
                        $('#mainFrame')[0].src = "LoadingPage.aspx";
                    }
                });$('a[name="dia"]').click(function(){
        $('#mainFrame')[0].src = this.file;
        $('#dialog').data('title.dialog', this.innerText); 
     $('#dialog').dialog('open');
     return false;
       });

Comment: if (document.getElementById('hidIsAdmin').value == "1"){
           document.getElementById('liAdmin').style.display = 'block';
           document.getElementById('liReports').style.display = 'block';
       }else {
           $('#liAdmin').remove();
           $('#liReports').remove();
           
       }
                if (document.getElementById('hidCreate').value == "1"){
           document.getElementById('liCreate').style.display = 'block';
       }else {
           $('#liCreate').remove();
                    $('.edit_icon_link').hide(0);           
       }

Comment: });
            function hideEditIcon(){
                $('.edit_icon_link').hide(0);           
   }

Comment: @user643062 please edit your question and add the code there, putting whole code in comments is not really readable.

Comment: Shadow Wizard  - done, please let me know if you need any other info. Everything was working fine and still the same code works fine if just replace following 3 lines with old versions. <link type="text/css" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" /> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js"></script>

Comment: Like I suggested before, make sure these new files exist and you don't have typo in the file name. Also, use `@` to notify e.g. @Shadow otherwise I won't see such comments.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem with IE8 because I was on a HTTPS page but loading jquery-ui package from a HTTP CDN.   As soon as I changed the url from

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js

to

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js

it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now using MVC4. So I had to add ***jquery-ui-1.8.20.js*** to the `BundleConfig.RegisterBundles()` under App_Start to get it to work:

```
bundles.Add( new ScriptBundle( "~/bundles/jquery" ).Include(
  "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
  "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js" ) );
```